# Kafka streams. Kstream - Kstream left join with right side, comming little later

Tags: apache-kafka, stream

I have following sccenario:

1. KStream A - main stream, that should be enriched some data from B Kstream.
2. Kstream B less intensive, than A. B∈A
3. KStream B records incoming later, than A.
4. Needed correct join whithout duplicates.
   What templates, approaches exists to resolve this issue?
   Maybe examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `KTable` Join:

Convert the `KStream B` into a `KTable`. This is useful if `KStream B` can be viewed as a changelog stream where each record represents the most current state. By joining `KStream A` with `KTable B`, you can enrich records in `A` with the latest available state from `B`.
**Note**: This only works if B∈A means that every key in `B` is also in `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this aproach suppose some "delay processor" for stream A?  It seems to be null in right side, because  record in A appears erliear than in B stream, and B KTable as result.

Comment: I see. You can also consider either adding a Delay to KStream A to allow time for the corresponding records in KStream B to arrive and update the KTable or you  could implement a reprocessing mechanism. If a join results in null, you can re-key the message to send it back to KStream A for reprocessing after a delay